# How to evaluate Nystrom approximation method?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, algebra, spectral-clustering

I want to evaluate the [Nystrom approximation method](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~malik/papers/FBCM-nystrom.pdf) for large matrices and as mentioned in the paper, this can be done by calculating the Schur complement but is too computationally expensive for large datasets. I am using the method perform spectral clustering, so i was thinking that it may be possible to evaluate the performance of it by finding the distance of the centroids (after k-means clustering of my embedding vectors) and my embedding vectors in order to see the how the Nystrom method performs for different choices of subset size (A matrix).

Comment: sklearn has code for the [Nystrom method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem.html) for kernel approximation.

Comment: i know but i implemented a parallel, faster implementation and the sklearn doesn't have any methods for evaluating its approximation